# How can I parse data between installed WinForm projects?

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

I have created an installer-project, that installs multiple projects, that I have created. There is a main-window that opens other programs on the click on a button. I want to parse data between the mainWindow and the program to open (string value), when the user clicks one of the buttons.
I use processes to start the programs the installer has installed to the application folder.

```
Process OpenProject1 = Process.Start(".\\" + "Project1.exe", "StringToParseHere");
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to parse data between the mainWindow and the program to open (string value)

For Project1.exe to read in the "StringToParseHere" when it starts, add code to the Main Event:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       if (args != null)
       {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) // Loop through array or command line parameters
        {
            string argument = args[i];
            MessageBox.Show(argument);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

If you need the argument value to go into say `Form1`, then make an overloaded class constructor and save to a private member variable, eg:

```
private string argumentParsedIn = string.empty; //This is the member variable

//base  class/form constuctor
Public Form1()
{
}

//Overloaded class/form constructor that takes a parameter
Public Form1(string argument)
{
   argumentParsedIn = argument;
}
```

One thing to be aware of is that the base class constructor for a WinForm Form has the `InitializeComponent();` method. So your overload constructor should call that method, a design pattern to do this is, eg:

### Solution

*Program.cs*

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
       if (args != null)
       {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) // Loop through array or command line parameters
        {
            string argument = args[i];
            //MessageBox.Show(argument);
        }
      }
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var application = new WindowsFormsApplication();
        application.Run(new Form1(argument)); //<-- see here is how I pass it
    }
}
```

*Form1.cs*

```
private string argumentParsedIn = string.empty; //This is the member variable
Public Form1() : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
   InitializeComponent();
}

Public Form1(string argument) : base() //<-- see here, adding the base will call the base constructor
{
   argumentParsedIn = argument;
}
```

Comment: see my edit for info.. In the `Main()` method when you instantiate `Form1` you will pass the argument as a parameter.

Comment: Argh! I can't figure out where to place what code...
I'm noob in code and english...

Comment: `application.Run(new Form1(argument));` <-- see my edit

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you very much for your patience!!  :D